# How to revert 8188eu driver update from git?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I tried to update the driver of my TP-Link adapter, but I messed up and now my adapter doesn't even work. It was working fine. I just want to undo whatever I did. These are the commands I ran. I found them on a post with a similar adapter.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu.ko
```

I hope that I didn't mess up big time. I don't want to try undo it myself and make it worse. I learned my lesson. I'd appreciate if someone could help me undo whatever I did.

Comment: A lot of drivers on the Git site are for older kernels, you should be fine with the drivers in Ubuntu - and a 5 kernel

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the link to the post that you followed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd to /lib/modules/latestest-kernel/
ls -R | grep 8188eu.ko
```

To find where the new driver is you can use:

```
root@ub7:/lib/modules/5.8.0-44-generic 
ls -R | grep 8188eu.ko  
r8188eu.ko 
find . -name r8188eu.ko 
./kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/r8188eu.ko
```

Rename `r8188eu.ko` to `r8188eu.ko.bak` (using `mv`).

Also check date of `r8188eu.ko` to see if is more recent. Then reboot the machine.

```
sudo reboot
```

If this does not work, reboot from older kernel, this would not changed.

If this works delete newest kernel - I could help let me know how you got on.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. All I needed to do was:

```
cd rtl8188eu
sudo make uninstall
```

Comment: Good to know that