# Installing wireless driver for TP-LINK TL-WN727N V5.20 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Desktop

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I'm quite new to Ubuntu. Plugged in my wifi adapter, signal is super weak. Plugged the same adapter into a Windows desktop in the same room and it was getting perfect signal.

TP-LINK TL-WN727N V5.20

Moved the router closer and managed to get it somewhat connected. However, the WiFi icon on the upper right varies up and down, and generally super low signal. Ping is very high as well.

Have read through a number of threads and can't find a specific solution yet.
From what I understood, drivers are not needed. But since the connection is abnormal, I reckon will need to update the drivers?

I've downloaded this driver from TP Link site: https://static.tp-link.com/2019/201905/20190524/TL-WN727N_V5.20_190514_Linux.zip
Not sure whether to directly install it, or to remove some previous drivers as mentioned in some threads I read here:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/868664/1737840
- [Low wireless signal with TP-Link TL-WN725N WiFi dongle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389153/low-wireless-signal-with-tp-link-tl-wn725n-wifi-dongle)

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop
Codename: jammy
Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-26-generic
Architecture: x86-64
GNOME version 42.9
Windowing System: Wayland
```

Attached info

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 8 channel internal hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04ca:00f9 Lite-On Technology Corp. Generic USB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1532:006e Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Essential
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 2357:0111 TP-Link 802.11n NIC
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`modinfo r8188eu | grep 0111`

```
alias:          usb:v2357p0111d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

`sudo dmesg | grep 8188`

```
[    8.797949] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    8.831710] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[   10.322240] r8188eu 3-10.3:1.0 wlx7c8bca071d51: renamed from wlan0
[   11.283613] r8188eu 3-10.3:1.0: Firmware Version 11, SubVersion 1, Signature 0x88e1
[ 5366.503201] r8188eu 3-10.3:1.0 wlxd0374589284f: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Yup Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop. Codename: jammy | Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-26-generic | Architecture: x86-64 | GNOME version 42.9 | Windowing System: Wayland

Comment: Please attach `lsusb` terminal command output while the dongle is connected

Comment: updated with `lsusb`

Comment: I believe the driver is already present in 6.2.0-xx. Please edit your question to show: `modinfo r8188eu | grep 0111` and: `sudo dmesg | grep 8188` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 as OP writes it has "generally super low signal. Ping is very high as well"

Comment: @chili555 updated with relevant info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it after scrubbing through a bunch of other questions + multiple trial & errors. Apparently the r8188eu driver is already present, but the wifi adapter needs to work with another 8188eu driver.

Solution below is to blacklist the r8188eu driver and load 8188eu driver.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git 
git clone -b v4.1.8_9499 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make
sudo make install
sudo -i
echo blacklist r8188eu  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo 8188eu  >>  /etc/modules
exit
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Check if r8188eu is blacklisted
`lsmod | grep r8188eu`

If it's still listed then remove it with `sudo rmmod r8188eu`

Load the installed 8188eu with `sudo modprobe 8188eu`

- Based off the answer here:
  https://askubuntu.com/a/1356730/1737840. Note that `echo “blacklist r8188eu”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` in one of the answers there should be `echo blacklist r8188eu  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- the latest git from [lwfinger](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu) for rtl8188eu didn't work, and had to clone from an earlier version (answered by https://askubuntu.com/a/612341/1737840)

Reboot and voila.

Some other answers that helped:

1. how to revert after installing the latest 8188eu driver from git and wifi adapter was completely missing (https://askubuntu.com/a/1321193)
2. Cross-referenced deviwiki.com to find out the exact model of adapter I had, based on the ID from `lsusb`, to find out that the driver needed is r8188eu
3. I found answers for TL-WN725N V2, and as I had this adapter lying around, tried using it to solve my situation. Got it working, swapped it out for the TL-WN727N, and it worked directly as well!